# How to find particular solution for infinity

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the following:

$$ e^{2x}\frac{dy}{dx} + 1 = 0 $$

And I now have the following general solution:

$$ y(x) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-2x} + C $$

How can I find the particular solution when $y$ approaches $2$ as $x$ approaches infinity?

Thanks :)

Comment: Hint: $2=y(\infty)=\frac12e^{-2\infty}+C$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It is highly recommended that you provide your own background and thoughts on this question. This will allow other users to come up with more appropriate and specific answers. In this regard, my immediate question is: Have you tried to compute the limit of your general solution when $x\to\infty$?

Answer (score 2):

Three steps:

- In the general solution, calculate the value of the limit $$\lim_{x\to \infty}y(x)$$
- Set the limit to $2$
- Solve the equation for $C$